# Why can't I pass a type dynamically to isintance()?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to get a datatype from an object and I am comparing it to a variable in isinstance.

Something like this. `BaseModel` comes from pydantic.

```
class ColSchema(BaseModel):    
    display: str
    internal: str
    data_type: str

schema = [
          ColSchema(display="Status", internal="status", data_type="str"),
          ColSchema(display="Mobile Number", internal="mobile_number", data_type="str"),
          ColSchema(display="DPD", internal="dpd", data_type="float")
          ]

for item in schema:
    if isinstance(variable, item.data_type):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

It give me this error.
`TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a type, a tuple of types, or a union`

What am I getting wrong here?

I can do `type(...)==type(...)`, but my linter is very unhappy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ColSchema.data_type` is a string when you do `ColSchema(display="Status", internal="status", data_type="str")`.

You should have something like `ColSchema(display="Status", internal="status", data_type=str)`.

You should also use `Type` on your `data_type`, as described in [pydantic docs](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/types/#type).

```
from typing import Type

class ColSchema(BaseModel):    
    display: str
    internal: str
    data_type: Type

schema = [
          ColSchema(display="Status", internal="status", data_type=str),
          ColSchema(display="Mobile Number", internal="mobile_number", data_type=str),
          ColSchema(display="DPD", internal="dpd", data_type=float)
          ]

for item in schema:
    if isinstance(variable, item.data_type):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: Could do it in a normal class but I have a pydantic class for the ColSchema and I cannot pass it that way.

Comment: @ShouryaDwivedi check the example. Pydantic has exactly this use case.

Comment: I just did. Should've checked it first. That works. Thank you so much!